# sp_reset_connection taking a long time to run

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I've got an application where all the sprocs are running nice and quick, but the sp_reset_connection calls between them are taking anything up to 20 seconds. I've looked at locking and blocking but can't see any happening and don't understand how this would effect sp_reset_connection.
Help!

Comment: Are you sure that is taking 20s? How do you measure? Such long times for `sp_reset_connection` would be *very* unusual.

Comment: The app wasn't running at it's normal speed so I performed a trace and got the duration from that - I've triple checked it because it's so weird.

Comment: If it takes 20 seconds, then you can actually observe it in `sys.dm_exec_requests` and see what is the `wait_time`, `wait_type` and `wait_resource`. Can you look at those fields and see what they show for SPIDs in `sp_reset_connection`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what the issue was.
It looks like when you run a trace the data gets written as part of this sproc, this means that if you're tracing into a table and the insert speed isn't stellar everything grinds to a halt.